# Возможные значения statusTxt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xhr

Какие возможные значения есть у statusTxt кроме success и error?

Comment: смотря в каком контексте

Comment: например "success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"

Comment: Что за `statusTxt`? Если речь про второй параметр `String textStatus` в `complete` у `jQuery.ajax()`, то все значения перечислены в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): `"success"`, `"notmodified"`, `"nocontent"`, `"error"`, `"timeout"`, `"abort"`, и `"parsererror"`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "success")
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        });
    });
}); вот пример. спасибо, скорее всего ответ дан  верный

Comment: Полный список https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status понятно что статусы будут не все из списка.